# After breakfast, egg plate clean up

Tags: eggs

I wash breakfast plates for about 800 people every morning, I scrub the plates before putting them in the dishwashe, is there some kind of chemical I can use to break down the egg protien and no longer have to scrub? - tired hands and all!

Comment: 800 plates?  That's well past the point that I'd work on mounting one of those motorized buffing machines (for cars) on a stand, so that I could just hold a plate under it and move it around a bit, without needing all of the elbow grease.

Comment: The chemical is called "dishwasher detergent" - it's formulated exactly for this job, removing food from plates without mechanical scrubbing. Have you tried not scrubbing at all (I never do it with my plates) and/or using a stronger setting on the dishwasher? Also, if you are using tabs, stop, use separate powder and buffing liquid.

Comment: Pre-scrubbing or rinsing renders a dishwasher pointless. Modern detergents and dishwashers are more than capable of dealing with greasy and/or eggy plates.

Answer (score 6):

I feel you pain. I spent 2 summers cleaning dishes to help pay for summer camp and that was only 100 campers (3 meals a day). 800 eggy dishes is not fun!

Getting egg off doesn't require anything special, just a soak in cold soapy water for a few minutes. Egg is a mix of protein and fat. Fat comes off better in warm or hot water but proteins come off much better in cold or cool water as heat makes the proteins stickier. If you can, set aside a container of some kind with cool soapy water and put loads of the plates into it. Soak as long as you can, then pull them out a few at a time and wash the gunk off with a sponge, then get into the dishwasher right away. If you're scrubbing you're working too hard!

Comment: I wash a dishwasher in a restaurant a few years ago. Soaking them beforehand works quite well, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are a dishwasher at a restaurant.  You need to form a big buffer of stacked plates waiting to be washed.  Maybe three stacks, 40 high each.  You will be building the stack on one side and pulling dishes to wash from the stack on the other side.  There will be some sliding of stacks.  Here is the KEY PART of the process.  You need to constantly spray your plate buffer with hot water at the edge of the stack, filling each plate with a bit of hot water.  If you keep them wet and hot, the plates coming off the front stack will have been soaking while the hundred or so plates have been cleaned and will clean with just a spray.

Answer (score -1):

I known what you mean on Saturday or sunday we would have soft boil egg .
after eating the egg , the york remains on bowl or plate.
i usually running with cold water and use brush if you have one or back of sponge ( rough side). if it still don't come out use a little hand washing dishes deg.
If you have rough sponge like yellow one use that one or pink one too.
If you don't load dishes into dishwasher straight away, get empty tub or use sink to fill up with cold water .
this also work with milk remained.